# Is it safe to create a symlink to a shared library with an older version number?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, backwards-compatibility

I recently configure a new server with the last Debian 9 and I have to run a non-official application. The problem is this application require an older version of a shared library:

```
$ ./myapp
./myapp: error while loading shared library: libmicrohttpd.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Indeed, I don't have this version of libmicrohttpd installed:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.12
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.12.39.0
```

According to the policy of my company, I can't change the apt source list to get a previous version of libmicrohttpd. So, I want to know if it's safe to create a symlink like that:

```
# ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.12.39.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.10
```

I had a look on the [ABI/API changes review](https://abi-laboratory.pro/?view=timeline&l=libmicrohttpd) for this library and every version unless one are backward compatible. For the only [version without full backward compatibility](https://abi-laboratory.pro/index.php?view=objects_report&l=libmicrohttpd&v1=0.9.46&v2=0.9.47), it's because the `libmicrospdy.so.0.0.0` was removed from the package.

So, what do you think, is it safe or should I expect some unwanted behaviors? If it's risky, what can I do without install any new non-official packages on my system?

Comment: "Safe" is a probably not a guarantee that anyone will give you. Unexpected behavior could occur. You can always try it and see if it appears to work, but it's hard to say for sure what will happen. Alternatively, can you build this application against this shared library version instead? Are there ways to pass this up the chain of command at your company so that you can get the tools and software you need to do your job?

Comment: @AKstat _"can you build this application against this shared library version instead?"_ No because the application should be backward compatible with older version of libmicrohttpd.

Comment: I was wondering if you could create a symbolic link to ver.10 instead of shadowing ver.12, i.e. like this `# ln -s /path/to/your/libmicrohttpd.so.10 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmicrohttpd.so.10`